# How do I add but not track files in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I want to move a web project into a TFS repository so other developers can work on it.  In addition to the source files, I want to add a SQL data file that lives in the App_Data, but I don't want its changes to be tracked. During the initial checkout of the entire repository, I want developers to get  a fresh baseline copy of the database, but I don't want changes to the database file to be checked in.  Is there a way to do this in TFS? FYI, I am using TFS 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a *Local Workspace*, which is the default in TFS 2012, then you should add these files to your [`.tfignore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx) after you have checked in the initial revision.

(If you are using *Server Workspaces*, then developers should simply not check out the file.)

Comment: So the other developers would just clone the repo which contains the .tfignore and they won't have to worry about it?

Comment: @user148298 If they make changes to the files, it will not be detected.  They can still go out of their way to manually pend a change (by running `tf edit`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can cloak the file so that the workspace ignores it. Right-click the file in Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio, select the `Advanced` sub-menu, and then click on `Cloak`.

Comment: Cloaking implies that the file will not be downloaded.